# Encontrar quais itens foram marcados - Ajuda com lógica

Tags: c#, checkbox, matemática

Tenho 4 Checkbox, que ao ser selecionados vão atribuindo seus valores em uma variável.
O resultado será salvo em apenas um campo no BD. Na hora de carregar esses Checkbox, eu preciso fazer uma conta para saber quais foram selecionados...Como fazer isso?

Exemplo:

combobox a = 2

combobox b = 4

combobox c = 16

combobox d = 8

Se eu selecionei o A e o B, a soma dará 6.

Na hora de pegar esses dados, preciso pegar esse valor e selecionar os Checkboxs A e B...como fazer essa conta?

Comment: Não poderia criar um if com as combinações possiveis?

Comment: é axo que sim...vou tentar...queria ver um jeito melhor de se fazer isso...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A forma como você está a dar os valores a cada um dos check box é como se cada um deles representassem um bit.

O peso de cada bit é função da sua posição na representação binária:

Da direita para a esquerda os pesos são os seguintes:

```
Posição 0 - 2^0 = 1
Posição 1 - 2^1 = 2
Posição 2 - 2^2 = 4
Posição 3 - 2^3 = 8
Posição 4 - 2^4 = 16
Posição 5 - 2^5 = 32
Posição 6 - 2^6 = 64
Posição 7 - 2^7 = 128
```

O seu valor em decimal é igual à soma dos pesos cujos bits estão *set*(com valor 1).

Se você tiver o checkbox 2 e o checkbox 4 checados é o equivalente à representação binária `00000110` = 6

Para saber se um bit está setado num valor decimal usa-se a função lógica bitwise:

```
(b & (1 << pos)) != 0;
```

Esta expressão retorna `true` se o *bit* na posição *pos* do numero b está setado.

### Implementação:

Vamos usar a propriedade *Tag* de cada *CheckBox* para guardar o equivalente à sua posição num número em representação binária:

```
checkBox2.Tag = 1;
checkBox4.Tag = 2;
checkBox8.Tag = 3;
checkBox16.Tag = 4;
```

Vamos criar dois métodos auxiliares.

```
//Retorna o peso do CheckBox
private int getPeso(CheckBox checkBox)
{
    return (int)Math.Pow(2,checkBox.Tag)
}

// Retorna true se a posição 'pos' em 'valor' está setada
private bool needToCheck(int valor, int pos)
{
    return (valor & (1 << pos)) != 0;
}
```

Para ser possível aceder aos *CheckBox* num *foreach* vamos colocá-los num *Painel*

Método para calcular o valor a guardar no banco:

```
private int getValor()
{
    int valor = 0;
    foreach (Control control in panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (control is CheckBox) 
        {
            if(control.Checked) valor = valor + getPeso(control);
        }
    }
    return valor;
}
```

Método para checar os *CheckBox* em função do valor guardado no banco.

```
private void doChecks(int valor)
{
    foreach (Control control in panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (control is CheckBox) 
        {
            control.Checked = needToCheck(valor, control.Tag);
        }
    }
}
```

### Utilização

Para calcular e guardar o valor:

```
int valor = getValor();
gravarValorNoBanco(valor);
```

Para checar os *CheckBox*

```
int valor = lerValorDoBanco();
doChecks(valor);
```

**Note que este código não necessita de ser alterado, qualquer que seja o número de** ***CheckBox's***

---

Se quiser fazer de uma forma mais direta não usando o Painel nem *CheckBox.Tag*

Calcular:

```
int valor =  0;
if(checkBox2.Checked) valor = valor + 2;
if(checkBox4.Checked) valor = valor + 4;
if(checkBox8.Checked) valor = valor + 8;
if(checkBox16.Checked) valor = valor + 16;
gravarValorNoBanco(valor);
```

Checar:

```
int valor = lerValorDoBanco();
checkBox2.Checked = (valor & (1 << 1)) != 0;
checkBox4.Checked = (valor & (1 << 2)) != 0;
checkBox8.Checked = (valor & (1 << 3)) != 0;
checkBox16.Checked = (valor & (1 << 4)) != 0;
```

Comment: Ramaral, eu tentei entender sua resposta mas nao entendi... Mas fiquei interessado em fazer essa conta atraves de binarios...pode me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Tive que me ausentar mas irei terminar a resposta.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Parabens Ramaral! Eu ainda nao testei a sua resposta, mas foi tudo bem explicado, obrigado por sua dedicação!

Comment: Alguma dúvida é só perguntar.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer utilizando operadores [bitwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation), utilizando seus valores escalares conforme demonstrou com

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c = 4;
var d = 8;
var e = 16;
var f = 32;
```

O teste para salvar o resultado dos campos selecionados seria com o bitwise `|`, digamos que sejam selecionados `a`, `b` e `f`:

```
var r = a | b | f; //35
```

Nesse caso o valor a ser salvo no banco de dados seria o valor de `r` `35`.

Pra selecionar os checkboxes a partir do valor resultante, você pode usar o operador `&`:

```
bool isA = (r & a) != 0;
bool isB = (r & b) != 0;
bool isC = (r & c) != 0;
bool isD = (r & d) != 0;
bool isE = (r & e) != 0;
bool isF = (r & f) != 0;
```

Nesse caso com `r = 35` então `isA`, `isB` e `isF` seriam `true`.

Então com estruturas de repetição você consegue resolver o problema com poucas linhas.

Answer (score -1):

Se você tiver eventos nos checkboxes, basta que você pegue o valor de cada um e adicione somando a uma variável. Depende da linguagem que você está usando. Se você quiser fazer um jeito mais simples que (talvez) funcione para tudo, você pode simplesmente ir adicionando os valores selecionados a um vetor e no final somar todas as posições.

Mas a solução está em verificar QUANDO os botões foram pressionados e adicionar o valor. Não depois.